# Convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n^3+x^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n^3+x^{2n}}$$

Here is what I've done :

$$|\frac{nx^n}{n^3+x^{2n}}|<|\frac{nx^n}{n^3}|=|\frac{x^n}{n^2}|$$$

Since series on $RHS$ would converge for $|x|<1$, then whenever $|x|<1$ is satisfied $LHS$ would converge. However answer is

LHS converges $\forall \epsilon R$ real numbers.

Comment: Try some things: $x=1,2$ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1.** Assume $|x|\le1$, then
$$
\sum_1^\infty \left|\frac{nx^n}{n^3+x^{2n}} \right|\le \sum_1^\infty \frac{n|x|^n}{n^3} \le \sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} <\infty
$$ and the given series is *absolutely convergent*.

**Case 2.** Assume $|x|>1$, then
$$
\sum_1^\infty \left|\frac{nx^n}{n^3+x^{2n}} \right|\le \sum_1^\infty \frac{n|x|^n}{|x|^{2n}} = \sum_1^\infty \frac{n}{|x|^{n}}  <\infty
$$ and the given series is *absolutely convergent*, where we have used this standard [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn/1706005#1706005).

Comment: For $|x|>1$  a very elementary finish can be: When $n\geq 3$ and $|x|=1+y $ with $ y>0$ we have:  $|x|^n=(1+y)^n\geq 1+y\binom {n}{1}+y^2\binom {n}{2}+y^3\binom {n}{3}>y^3 \binom {n}{3},$  so $0<n/|x|^n<ny^{-3} /\binom {n}{3}=6y^{-3}/((n-1)(n-2))$...............+1